# tf operation control_inputs vs inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow

In [`tf.Operation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation), what's the difference between `control_inputs` and `inputs`? `tf.Operation` describes them separately, but in the normal course of events I would expect 'every data input is ready' to be exactly the condition for the current operation being able to run. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tensorflow, one can add extra dependencies via [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) function, which are obeyed by the tensorflow in addition to the ordinary dependencies (which correspond to the inputs). This is exactly what [`tf.Operation.control_inputs`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation#control_inputs) holds.

Here's an example:

```py
a = tf.Variable(name='a', initial_value=1.0, trainable=False)
b = tf.Variable(name='b', initial_value=0.0, trainable=False)  
c = tf.add(a, b, name='sum')

op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('sum')
print(list(op.inputs))    # [<tf.Tensor 'a/read:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'b/read:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
print(op.control_inputs)  # []
```

It's a standard situation, and unsurprisingly `c` has only 2 ordinary inputs and no `control_inputs`. Upon evaluation, `c` value will be `1.0`.

But if you add an extra dependency, it'll change the graph and the way the computation goes:

```py
a = tf.Variable(name='a', initial_value=1.0, trainable=False)
b = tf.Variable(name='b', initial_value=0.0, trainable=False)

dependent_op = tf.assign(b, a * 3, name='dependent_op')
with tf.control_dependencies([dependent_op]):
  c = tf.add(a, b, name='sum')

op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('sum')
print(list(op.inputs))    # [<tf.Tensor 'a/read:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'b/read:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
print(op.control_inputs)  # [<tf.Operation 'dependent_op' type=Assign>]
```

Note that the list of `inputs` didn't change, but `control_inputs` now contains the `dependent_op`. Tensorflow guarantees that `dependent_op` will be evaluated before `sum`, as a result, `c` is going to get the value **`4.0`**. If you define `c` without `tf.control_dependencies` block, `c` will be evaluated to **`1.0`**, because `dependent_op`, even though it's in the graph, won't be executed.